# Will WPF be relevant with Windows 8?

Tags: wpf, windows-8

With windows 8 demonstrating 'native HTML 5 apps'.

The first thing that I think of is whether WPF has a place in this HTML 5 world. It kind of seems like Silverlight will stick around but I must ask : Where does WPF fit into the bigger picture microsoft is painting ?

Comment: Maybe Ms decided that WPF is too hard to learn and people are unwilling to do so? (I've already been through that road and it wasn't like the easiest thing I've done in my life)

Comment: This is a yes or no question... it is not subjective. I am unclear as to why it was closed.

Comment: vote to reopen if you are interested in seeing more answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

All that's been said is that this (and where Silverlight , XNA, and C++ fit in) will be announced at the BUILD conference in September.  Lots of rumors and speculation, but no announcements.

Answer (score 1):

It's too early to tell. Just because Microsoft demoed a particular feature doesn't mean it's dropping everything else.